How to obtain the evolutionary animal?
How to obtain some organisms:

An English verb (2) → A venomous insect (3)
A Spanish pronoun, without the diacritic (2) → A long fish (3)
An English color (3) → A plant, not for eating (4)
A German article (3) → An ungulate (4)
An English verb (3) → An edible plant (4)

How can I obtain the evolutionary animal (5)?

First analyse the examples to work out what's being represented here:

 An English verb (2) → A venomous insect (3) i.e. BE → B[E]E
 A Spanish pronoun, without the diacritic (2) → A long fish (3) i.e. EL → E[E]L
 An English color (3) → A plant, not for eating (4) i.e. RED → RE[E]D
 A German article (3) → An ungulate (4) i.e. DER → DE[E]R
 An English verb (3) → An edible plant (4) i.e. BET → BE[E]T

 In other words, we are looking at words that can become other words by the addition of an 'E' before their last letter.

Now, ask: Who is 'the evolutionary animal (5)'?

 With the video-games tag, this must surely be EEVEE, a 5-letter Pokémon that can evolve into many different Pokémon dependent on particular conditions being met. A Pokémon professor would no doubt consider 'Eevee' the prime example of 'the evolutionary creature'...



So how can we obtain it?

 Similarly to the leading examples, we need to take a word and insert an 'E' before the last letter. This can be done through:

 A Belgian robotics company (4) → The evolutionary animal (5) i.e. EEVE → EEVEE.

Alternatively - a nicer rule suggested by @msh210 in comments, below:

 Instead of inserting an 'E' before the last letter, this can also be achieved via the rule of double all instances of the letter 'E' (or add another 'E' after each 'E'). So instead we can achieve the same via:

 The first woman, according to Genesis (3) → The evolutionary animal (5) i.e. EVE → EEVEE.


@msh210 Thanks, I've added it now. It would actually have been quite tricky for the OP to differentiate my solution from yours by providing an example to show what would have happened in another instance with two of these operations being required as there aren't many out there. Possibly, "Lovelorn cartoon skunk (4)" may have been a good starting point :)
